# Selecionar Arquivo pelo WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, navegador-de-internet

Tenho um arquivo HTML com o seguinte código:

```
<form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Ao clicar no botão, ele me abre uma Caixa de dialogo para selecionar um arquivo, queria fazer isso em um `TWebBrowser` do Delphi, informando o diretório do arquivo em um `TEdit` para que o arquivo seja adicionado sem a necessidade de clicar no botão para selecionar o arquivo pelo `Dialog`.

Comment: Supostamente, pela manobra que você quer fazer, me parece que você precisa enviar um e-mail com anexo, certo ? Porque você não monta uma estrutura de envio de e-mail dentro da aplicação(Indy) ao invés de tentar usar a página como ferramenta ?